# PHP, как реализовать цепочку сообщений боты в ВК

Tags: php, вконтакте, бот

подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать цепочку сообщений бота в моей группе ВК

(бот в сообществе ВК, который отвечает на сообщение пользователям которые написали ему)

Я **понимаю** как сделать ответ на определенные команды, к примеру:

```
Вова: !дата
Бот: сейчас 12 09 2022 21:50
```

Или

```
Вова: !правила
Бот: Правила сообщества: ...
```

**Но как реализовать вот такое:**

```
Вова: !подать заявку
Бот: Напишите ваше настоящее имя?
Вова: Владимир
Бот: Теперь мне понадобится ваш номер телефона:
Вова: +79000000000
Бот: Ваша заявка принята! Пожалуйста, ожидайте подтверждения Вашей заявки администратором группы
```

Заранее всем большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вот по ссылке разбирают как такое сделать.
https://kotoff.net/article/php/70-kak-sdelat-cepochku-soobschenij-anketu-dlja-bota-vk-na-php.html

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)